# Python/Django - initial/default admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

After a user has logged into the admin interface is it possible to redirect them to a specific page?

I want to redirect to the list of entries for a particular model.

I'm using Django 1.3

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You can set the default redirect url (on login) in your settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/admin/mymodel/"
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#login-redirect-url

Comment: That didn't work for me. It probably works for developer defined logins but not django.contrib.admin. I'm guessing that the contrib.admin page _is_ providing a 'next' parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [ticket 14510](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14510) .
Seems django admin doesn't support LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL settings and you should subclass AdminSite.